# How to check the condition in given three array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, php-5.6

I am having three arrays

1. topicsSelected
2. relavantGroups
3. topicAssingned

```php
$topicsSelected = [ "T-100","T-600"];

$relavantGroups = [[ "id" => "G-001","name" => "3 A","active"=> false ], ["id"=> "G-002","name"=> "3 B","active"=> false]  ];

$topicAssingned = [
    "G-001" => [
        "groupID" => "G-001",
        "groupName" => "3 A",
        "topics" => [
            "T-100" => [
                "topicID" => "T-100"
            ],
            "T-200" => [
                "topicID" => "T-200"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "G-002" => [
        "groupID" => "G-002",
        "groupName" => "3 B",
        "topics" => [
            "T-400" => [
                "topicID" => "T-400"
            ],
            "T-500" => [
                "topicID" => "T-500"
            ]
        ]
    ],
];
```

$topicsSelected array values(T-100 or T-600) at least one value should present in $topicAssingned array, based on groupID(G-001). $topicAssingned under topics , topicID : T-100 is **present** , so `Disable : D`

$topicsSelected array values(T-100 or T-600) at least one value should present in $topicAssingned array, based on groupID(G-002). $topicAssingned under topics , topicID : T-100 & T-600 is **not present** , so `Disable : A`

Expected output:

```
[
     "id": "G-001",
    "name": "3 A",
    "active": false,
    "Disable" : "D"
],
[
     "id": "G-002",
    "name": "3 B",
    "active": false,
    "Disable" : "A"
]
```

> My Code

```
    foreach ($relavantGroups as &$g) {
    $found = false;
    foreach ($topicAssingned as $key => $assigned) {
        if ($key === $g["id"]) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    $g["disable"] = $found ? "D" : "A";
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($relavantGroups);
```

> My Output

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => G-001
            [name] => 3 A
            [active] => 
            [disable] => D
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => G-002
            [name] => 3 B
            [active] => 
            [disable] => D
        )

)
```

Comment: Can you explain it more? where is your third array comparison code? and what is the issue are you facing? here I only see the active element is empty and disable is different? am I right? can you give a JSON format of all three arrays so we can try at our end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this snippet,

```
foreach ($relavantGroups as &$g) {
    $found = false;
    foreach ($topicAssingned as $key => $assigned) {
        if ($key === $g["id"]) {
            $temp  = array_keys($assigned['topics']); // fetching all topic ids
            $intr  = array_intersect($topicsSelected, $temp); // checking if there are any matching values between topicSelected and traversed values
            $found = (!empty($intr) ? true : false); // if found return and break
            break;
        }
    }
    $g["disable"] = $found ? "D" : "A";
}
print_r($relavantGroups);
```

[array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) — Computes the intersection of arrays
[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => G-001
            [name] => 3 A
            [active] => 
            [disable] => D
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => G-002
            [name] => 3 B
            [active] => 
            [disable] => A
        )

)
```

**[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2038bf28077c7df6027b48c3df92bfd859114062)**

Comment: Some explanation of what you have done and why it solved OP's problem is always useful to help others understand your solution.